# want to use bind to point to local Nginx box for cache purposes

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, centos7, bind

Trying to set up bind to redirect DNS requests of certain domains to my local Nginx server to cache downloads to avoid multiple downloads of the same data.

I have made both recursive and authoritative bind boxes before but I don't know what to look up to find guides for what I'm trying to do.   I know its something to do with zones but I'm not sure where to go from there.

If any guides exist for this, a point in that direction would be fantastic.

I'm running CentOS 7 but I don't imagine that shouldn't make any difference.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at bind RPZ feature.

Comment: seems to be exactly what I'm looking for... many thanks